# Just updated to Yosemite: Where is my garageband?

Tags: macos, garageband

So I used to have Garageband on my Mac before I updated to Yosemite. After the update, it is no longer here. Where do I now find Garageband after the update?

I tried to look on the App store, thinking maybe now you have to download it if you want it but they only have one for sale. I never paid for it, it was just always installed and used on both my Macs.

Comment: I don't know what happened to your old version, unless it was marked as incompatible, in which case it will be in MacintoshHD > Incompatible Software... but if you had an old version, v6 is most likely as it was on the OS installer DVD for a time, it likely hasn't seen an update since. Apple want you to buy v10 over again.